# Corruption without mentioning array

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am fairly new to c++ and am wondering why my array keeps getting corrupted. It goes through the double for loops several times before corrupting ammo_bank, although it is properly assigned before that line. It then gives me the error writing violation

```
class bullet{
public:
    int x, y, damage, speed;
    char direction;
};

bullet * ammo_bank[100];
void render(player avatar, riflemen enemy){
    bullet projectile;
    int counter1, counter2, icurrentammo;
    icurrentammo = current_ammo -1;
    for (counter1 = 0; counter1 <=SCREEN_HEIGHT; counter1++){
        for (counter2 = 0; counter2 <=SCREEN_WIDTH; counter2++){     // corruption occurs a few times before here
            screen[counter1][counter2] = '.';
        }
    }
    system("cls");
    screen [avatar.y][avatar.x] = AVATAR_SYMBOL;
    screen [enemy.y][enemy.x] = RIFLEMEN_SYMBOL;
    while (icurrentammo >= 0){
        projectile = *ammo_bank[icurrentammo];                 // Writing error
        screen[projectile.x][projectile.y] = BULLET_SYMBOL;
        projectile.x ++;
        icurrentammo --;
    }

    for (counter1 = 0; counter1 <=SCREEN_HEIGHT; counter1++){
        cout << endl;
        for (counter2 = 0; counter2 <=SCREEN_WIDTH; counter2++){
            cout << screen[counter1][counter2];
        }
    }


void playerShoot(player avatar){
    ammo_bank[current_ammo] = new bullet(); // Create the MyClass here.
    bullet projectile = *ammo_bank[current_ammo];
    projectile.x = avatar.x + 1;
    projectile.y = avatar.y;
    projectile.speed = 2;
    projectile.direction = 'f';
    projectile.damage = 1;
    *ammo_bank[current_ammo] = projectile;
    current_ammo++;
}
```

Comment: I have bought a book today, it's called 'Accelerated C++', ;)

Comment: What does that have to do with anything

Comment: update your example to show how you declare screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is screen[][] declared.  If it is screen[SCREEN_HEIGHT][SCREEN_WIDTH], then your problem is that you are using <= when you should just use <.

Comment: Also, you'll probably want to check on `screen[projectile.x][projectile.y] = BULLET_SYMBOL` that `projectile.x < SCREEN_WIDTH && projectile.x >=0 && projectile.y < SCREEN_HEIGHT projectile.y >= 0`

Comment: That works, but it makes these weird ASCII characters at the bottom if i do that

Comment: @user998335 the point is an array is indexed from 0 to count-1, so very common is to find for(i=0; i<count; ++i) etc., not i<=count because that is one beyond the end of your array, and you will corrupt something if you write into array[count]

Comment: @MartyE +1, and also, notice there is no limit or checking done on current_ammo, so ammo_bank[100] could also be overrun

Comment: @user998335 If you are getting weird characters on the last row after fixing the array to not overflow, then you probably also need to fix your display loop to not overflow.